# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to .jcall(object, "[[Ljava/lang/String;", "staticMethod", methodParam)

Tags: r, rjava

I'm trying to call some java code from R,
I've compiled the java class and I can execute the code manually - it works fine!

But when calling the same bit of code from R, it's throwing this error:

    `4.
    stop(structure(list(message = "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", 
    call = .jcall(obj, "[[Ljava/lang/String;", "findPattern", location), 
    jobj = new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x00000000195abf30>, 
        jclass = "java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException")), class = 
    c("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException",  ... 
    3.
    .jcheck() 
    2.
    .jcall(obj, "[[Ljava/lang/String;", "findPattern", location) 
    1.
    findPattern()`

Since manually running java runs fine, the problem seems to be from my execution of java from r.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class PatternFinder
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9])(4-5)([asuy])");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length == 1)
        {
            findPattern(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("No arguments specified");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static String[][] findPattern(String filePath)
    {
        String[][] df = null;
        List<String> g1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> g2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> g3 = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                while (matcher.find())
                {
                    g1.add(matcher.group(1).trim());
                    g2.add(matcher.group(2).trim());
                    g3.add(matcher.group(3).trim());
                }

            }
            df = new String[g1.size()][3];
            for (int i = 0; i < g1.size(); i++)
            {
                df[i][0] = g1.get(i);
                df[i][1] = g2.get(i);
                df[i][2] = g3.get(i);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return df;
    }
}
```

Here is the R code:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_45", "C:\\PatternFinder")
obj=.jnew("PatternFinder")

patternFinder <-function(location = "C:\\largeFile.txt")
{
  result = .jcall(obj,"[[Ljava/lang/String;", "findPattern", location)
  df = sapply(result,.jevalArray)
  df
}

patternFinder()
```